# Saving index values with non-zero elements in Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop, matrix

I have a one-dimensional array containing values and I'm trying to use a for loop to identify the index values associated with non-zero elements.

For the code below, non_zero_elements should contain the values 0, 1, and 4, but what I am getting is [1, 0, 0, 4, 0].

I tried referencing a similar thread ([Finding Non-Zero Values/Indexes in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56391656/finding-non-zero-values-indexes-in-numpy)) but couldn't identify the bug in my code.

```
a = [1,2,0,0,4,0]
non_zero_elements = []
i = 0
for i in a:
    if a[i] != 0:
        non_zero_elements.append(i)
        print('The value',a[i],'in index',i,'is a non-zero element.')
        i = i + 1
print('Non-zero elements: ',non_zero_elements)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way to solve this is with a list comprehension over an [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate), which gives you the index and the value, allowing you to filter on non-zero values:

```
a = [1,2,0,0,4,0]
non_zero_elements = [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v != 0]
print(non_zero_elements)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you were trying to do it, you meant to iterate over the indices and not the elements of list `a`.

```
a = [1,2,0,0,4,0]
non_zero_elements = []
i = 0
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if a[i] != 0:
        non_zero_elements.append(i)
        print('The value',a[i],'in index',i,'is a non-zero element.')
        i = i + 1
print('Non-zero elements: ',non_zero_elements)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback, it was spot on.

Answer (score 1):

`for i in a:` in this i is the value of items in a and not their index.

You can use `for i, v in enumerate(a):` to iterate over the list where `i` will be index and `v` will be the value at that index.

Alternately, you can use `for i in range(len(a)):` to iterate using the index and access a[i].

Comment: Thank you, Surender!